# CollectionView CurrentChanging into what?

Tags: c#, wpf, collectionview

When using a CollectionView in WPF and listening on CurrentChanging I want to cancel the change if the item being selected is not a valid item to select. The problem is I can't find out what item the CollectionView is changing to. If I don't know this I can't validate the item as selectable or not. How do I accomplish this with a CollectionView?

Comment: Same problem but no solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11472798/620360

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should prevent the selection of any invalid item. I would use the [IDataErrorInfo Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) and bind to [IsEnabled Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled.aspx).

Comment: The problem is I have to check validity remotely and I can't poll this information continously.